# Use Cookies to storage personalization info or setting preferences: does it persist when the user logged on to a new device

Tags: javascript, html, http

When we use cookies to storage personalization info or setting preferences for a given user, I know it is going to persist when the user is sticking with the same computer. But does it persist if the user is loggin using a different device?

If not, what should we do if we want preserve the user settings no matter where he/she logins?

Comment: Use a database?

Comment: @Peteris so does the data persist if the user is using a different device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cookies are not persistent

Cookies are temporary local storage. They will not persist if the user is using a different device. They will not persist if the user is using a different browser on the same device. They *may* persist on the same computer for some time, but that's not guaranteed and you should not rely on that. They will not persist on the same device for a prolonged time as it's reasonable and common to clear them periodically no matter if they have reached the expiry date that you have used, for example, privacy-focused settings that remove all cookies whenever closing the browser.

You can assume that cookies will persist throughout a single browsing session, and that's it. If you want to persist some data, you have to do it on *your* systems. Various types of databases are a common solution for that.